# A great circle on a sphere

Tags: spherical-trigonometry

The following proposition is from 'Spherical Geometry and Its Applications' by Marshall A. Whittlesey:

**Proposition 5.6** If two distinct points on a sphere are not antipodal then there exists a unique great circle passing through them [1]

Let there be two non-antipodal distinct points on a small circle of a sphere. I cannot imagine a great circle that passes through both of them. (Think of this small circle just below the 'equator' of the sphere and imagine the equator is on a horizontal plane) Could you help me understand this? Or do I misunderstand some concepts here?

[1] Whittlesey, Marshall A.(2020). Spherical Geometry and Its Applications. CRC Press Taylor & Francis Group.

Comment: If you draw the shortest path on the sphere between your two points, that path is a segment of the great circle you're looking for. (Maybe you've misunderstood the definition of a great circle?)

Comment: @Karl Any circle that has all its points on a sphere and whose diameter is equal to that of the sphere is a great circle. But, if I draw a path between my two points, won't that segment be an arc of the small circle I began with?

Comment: The arc of your small circle won't be the *shortest* path on the sphere.

Comment: Can you visualize a plane that contains your two points and the sphere's center? This plane intersects the sphere along a great circle. (This is ice1000's answer.)

Comment: Ok, I think I have just managed to visualize it in my head. Everything became full circle:D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple construction, using the fact that three points uniquely determine a plane if not collinear. Take the following three points:

- The given two points.
- The center of the sphere.

The plane determined by these three points should intersect with the sphere with a great circle.

1. The plane should pass through the center of the sphere (so it intersects with the sphere with a great circle) *and* through the two points provided.
2. The given two points are not antipodal so they are not collinear with the center.

Comment: That's right. And if points are antipodal then we cam draw infinitely many great circles.

Comment: @ice1000 I am really trying but I still cannot visualize it. Could you provide me with a visual with the great circle? I hope I am not demanding much.

Comment: @AliKıral: Form a triangle using the center and the two points. This triangle defines a plane. The intersection of this plane and the sphere will be a great circle and it will contain both points.